# How to prevent time overlap?

Tags: time, coldfusion, logic

I'm trying to fix my cfif statements that I use to compare date, start and end time. So first part of my if statements works fine, I set the logic to check for the dates if they are equal, if they are to compare start time in database with start time passed from the argument and same for end time. My code is breaking in this case if I already have:

```
Date: 01/31/2016 Start Time: 8:30 AM End Time: 9:50 AM
```

and I try to pass next three arguments:

```
Date 01/31/2016 Start Time 10:00 AM End Time: 10:40 AM
```

So my code should allowed this to be saved in data base since we do not have overlap for time slots. But that should be allowed only once for this date and time. But if I keep trying to save this more than once my code does not stop that. Here is my logic that use:

```
<cfif arguments.datepicker EQ qryTable1.DateMeet>
    <cfif ((arguments.StartTime LTE qryTable1.Stime AND arguments.EndTime LTE qryTable1.Stime) OR (arguments.StartTime GTE qryTable1.Etime AND arguments.EndTime GTE qryTable1.Etime))>
       <cfquery name="qryTable1" datasource="test">
           Insert Into Schedule(DateMeet, Stime, Etime)
           Values (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#arguments.datepicker#">,
                   <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#arguments.StartTime#">,
                   <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#arguments.EndTime#">)
       </cfquery>
    </cfif>  
<cfelse>
    <cfif arguments.datepicker EQ qryTable1.DateMeet>
         <cfquery name="qryTable1" datasource="test">
           Insert Into Schedule(DateMeet, Stime, Etime)
           Values (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#arguments.datepicker#">,
                   <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#arguments.StartTime#">,
                   <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_time" value="#arguments.EndTime#">)
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

I still can not find why my logic catch if I pick overlap time for the same date, but if I pick something that is out of range and save that once, allows me to do that multiple times. If anyone can see what is wrong with my logic please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a line drawing to develop the logic to ensure that time slots do not overlap. There are 7 cases to consider in total, but they can be reduced to 2 cases. If a and b don't overlap, the endDateTime of a is less than the startDateTime of b, or the endDateTime of a is less than the startDateTime of b.

So either:

```
    b         a
|-------| |-------|
```

or

```
    a         b
|-------| |-------|
```

Depending on your requirement, either < or <= could be used.

Comment: Nice explanation.  Though for the second part, did you mean to write "endDateTime of *b* less than the startDateTime of *a* "?

Comment: @user3023588 - Keep in mind CF is multi-threaded so there is a slight chance for race conditions using your current method. Consider performing the logic in SQL and only do the insert only there is no overlap. Use the "result" attribute to check the number of records affected. If it is `> 0` you know the insert was successful. Otherwise, it failed and you can ignore it or take some other action like throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a formatted comment.  First, troubleshoot if/else logic problems by looking at your data.  Start with something like this:

```
<cfif arguments.datepicker EQ qryTable1.DateMeet>
match
<cfelse>
no match
<cfdump var = "datepicker is #arguments.datepicker# and query is "#qryTable1.DateMeet#">
</cfif>
```

Carry on until you understand why things are happening the way they are.

You also have this:

```
<cfif ((arguments.StartTime LTE qryTable1.Stime 
AND arguments.EndTime LTE qryTable1.Stime) 
OR (arguments.StartTime GTE qryTable1.Etime 
AND arguments.EndTime GTE qryTable1.Etime))>

   <cfquery name="qryTable1" datasource="test">
       Insert Into Schedule(DateMeet, Stime, Etime)
```

etc.

You are performing logic on a query variable named qryTable1, and then running another query with that name.  Overwriting that variable may be causing a problem.

Still with that variable, it is not necessary to have a name attribute for cfquery tags that involve writing data.  In other words, this:

```
   <cfquery name="qryTable1" datasource="test">
       Insert Into Schedule(DateMeet, Stime, Etime)
```

could be this:

```
   <cfquery datasource="test">
       Insert Into Schedule(DateMeet, Stime, Etime)
```

Still with that variable, it is not clear that it is local to the function.  It is not scoped `local` and you didn't show the entire function.  If it's not local, that may be a problem.

Finally, comparing times in isolation can lead to problems around midnight.  The extra effort to use datetime (timestamp) variables is usually worthwhile.

Comment: *it is not necessary to have a name attribute for cfquery tags that involve writing data*  To clarify, only `select` statements return a result set. When used with an `insert/update/delete` the query variable will be undefined.